# discord.py can't work because of package missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a simple code:

```py
import discord
import threading #just prepare for future use
import subprocess # prepare also
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')
async def on_message(message):
    return message.channel.send(message)

client.run('TOKENNNNNN')
```

But when i trying to run this, i receive the folling trace-back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/projects/Discord bot.py", line 6, in <module>
    import discord
  File "D:\python\block shooter\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "D:\python\block shooter\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 27, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\Edison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\Edison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import events
  File "C:\Users\Edison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 14, in <module>
    import contextvars
  File "C:\Users\Edison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\contextvars.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _contextvars import Context, ContextVar, Token, copy_context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_contextvars'
```

I think this have something to do with `_contextvars`, so i try to install `contextvars`, but it can't seems to work to well... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? That may be causing the error.

Comment: yes i am using venv

Comment: i'll try to run it with python console

Comment: python console still failed me.

Comment: What you could do is try to update Python and all your dependencies to the latest version. Usually if you start from scratch and reinstall/resetup your environment, it fixes many problems.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: i think I updated all my package/pip, using pycharm's feature, I also tried using python console(not venv) to run, both fail, anyone have solution?